# how to set default Mockito answer for Spring Boot bean or how to set a proxy for Spring Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I find Mockito set default answer<sup>[[site]](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-)</sup>, I wanna know how to do that in Spring Boot?

```
OtherAbstract spy = mock(OtherAbstract.class, withSettings()
    .useConstructor().defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS));
```

I have not found any similar thing in [spybean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html).

I am writing tests for an old system. I wanna know where and what some Beans have done.

Comment: @MockBean has an answer property that can be set to CALLS_REAL_METHODS

Answer (score 0):

If your test is starting a Spring Test context (e.g. `@WebMvcTest`, `@SpringBootTest`, etc.), you can use `@MockBean` to replace or add a mocked version of the bean inside the test context.

You can then use Mockito to define the behaviour of the mocked bean.

Answer (score 0):

I used Spring AOP to replace the default answer of Mockito.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class MPNNotifyTest extends TestTemplate {

    @Aspect
    @Configuration
    static  class ServiceAspect {


        @Around("execution(* myproject.service.impl..*(..))")
        public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

            // start stopwatch
            Object retVal = pjp.proceed();

            String[] tmp = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName().split("\\.");
            String basename = tmp[tmp.length - 1];
            log.debug("{} signature: {}#{}", logPromptAOP, basename, pjp.getSignature().getName());
            log.debug("{} args: {} ", logPromptAOP, JSON.toJSONString(pjp.getArgs()));
            log.debug("{} return value: {}", logPromptAOP, JSON.toJSONString(retVal));

            // stop stopwatch
            return retVal;
        }
}
```